# Some confusion regarding potential energy

Tags: gravity, potential-energy

We know that gravitational fields are attractive. Their direction is inward. So if we go from a nearer point to a farther point the potential energy should increase, and the work done should be negative. But why is the work done positively, and the potential energy becoming more negative?? In the case of the electric field positive charge, the field is outward work done is positive and we get lower potential energy when going farther out, going in we get higher potential energy. I understand this but can't relate to the gravitational field. does the gravitational field work differently?

Comment: The work done by gravity when an object moves away from a point mass is negative. the potential energy becomes _less_ negative, not more negative. For the positive point charge you are right. The electrostatic potential is _less positive_ as you move away from the point charge because the electric field is pointing outward. I hope this sorts it all out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The potential energy does not increase in magnitude with distance; it gets more negative. Gravitational and electrostatic force are examples of inverse-square-law forces, which are INVERSELY proportional to the square of distance:
$$F=\frac{k}{r^2}$$. From this, we get that gravitational potential and electrostatic potential energy are inversely proportional to distance.
$$U=-\frac{k}{r}\because F=-\nabla U$$ Gravitational force is sometimes expressed like this, $$F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$ where $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ denotes the *unit vector* in the direction of the *radius vector*. If we consider the force acting on $m_1$, the radius vector points from $m_1$ to $m_2$, and conversely, the force acting on $m_2$ points from $m_2$ to $m_1$ (these forces are equal and opposite).

One way to describe force is $F=-\nabla U$. In one dimension, this means that force is equal to the rate of change of potential energy as the distance between the particles gets smaller. This means that the sign of gravitational potential energy will always be negative. When two masses get closer to each other, the potential energy gets more negative. **The sign convention relating work and potential energy is that $W=-\Delta U$**. When an object is dropped, the potential energy gets more negative, so work is positive. Conversely, when an object is picked up and brought to a height $h$, its potential energy increases by $mgh$ so its work decreases by $mgh$.

For electostatic potential energy, it's not the same because the sign of the potential energy depends on the charges. Coulomb's law in vector form states that $$\mathbf{F}=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r^2}\mathbf{\hat{r}}$$ implying $$U=-\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0|r|}$$. So to answer your last question, yes, gravitational field works differently, because although the two are very similar, mass cannot be negative while charge can.

Answer (score 0):

*But why is the work done positively, and the potential energy becoming more negative??*

You have a system which has potential energy.

Positive work is done by an **external** force on the system and the potential energy of the system increases.

For example, **Earth & ball system**.
You lift the ball up (positive **external** work done) and the gravitational potential energy of the Earth & ball system increases.